# How to pass props to a component for routing inside ListItem tag in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-props

Below is a code snippet:

```html
const AppList = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ListItem
          button
          component={Link}
          to="/MainComponent"
        >
        ..
        ..
        </ListItem>
      </div>
    </Router>
   )
 }
```

MainComponent route is defined in a starting page, and I want to pass props to that route, is there any way to do so?

Comment: How did you solved this? In case it got solved then

Comment: I used uselocation (Hooks) to do that

Answer (score 0):

before I start the code been taken from:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7956

hi you should create your own component that use the link and pass props to it like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router';
import { Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';

// The usage of React.forwardRef will no longer be required for react-router-dom v6.
// see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6056
const AdapterLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Link innerRef={ref} {...props} />
));

const CollisionLink = React.forwardRef(
  (props, ref) => <Link innerRef={ref} to="/getting-started/installation/" {...props} />,
);

export default function ButtonRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ListItem color="primary" component={AdapterLink} to="/">
        Simple case
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem component={CollisionLink}>Avoids props collision</ListItem>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

this code when you pass the to it will move to the AdapterLink so you can send it like so:
to={
pathname: '/template',
state: { something: 'something' }
}

Comment: Can you help me by breaking this code, like what exactly is happening here? How props are passed through link and can be used by the component defined in another page?

Comment: @AmitTiwari to access the state in the component you navigate to in FC access it from 
```let location = useLocation();``` and then ```location.state``` and then you get all the states

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk, the difference between `AdapterLink` and `CollisionLink` is that `AdapterLink` is reusable whereas `CollisionLink` has a fixed link in `to` prop, right?

Comment: Yes kinda the adapter give you much more reusable component